# If there are 10 people and 40 floors, what is the probability that the elevator makes less than 9 stops?

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble with this problem. I cannot figure out how to get the total number of possibilities of getting less than 9 stops. How would I go about calculating that value?

Comment: Presumably the people independently and uniformly choose a destination floor.  Do they choose it from $40$ floors or from $39$?  Are they all starting on the same floor, so the $39$ they choose from are the same set?  Many details need to be supplied before one can compute this reasonably.

Answer (score 1):

Use complementation.

You have 10 people selecting<sup>(how?)</sup>, independently<sup>(?)</sup>, from 40 destinations<sup>(or 39?)</sup>.

You want the probability that they *do not* select 9 or 10 stops.